# How to put restriction on duplicating values during a day

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Can you please help me with a code. My skills in coding poor if you can make it understandable for dummies. 
I have a user form where I need to put every time manually a number of inputs of the day. For example

```
2019/03/25 - input 1
2019/03/25 - input 2
2019/03/25 - input 3
```

etc. 
My task to restrict putting the same number  so there can't be a situation like this

```
2019/03/25 - input 1
2019/03/25 - input 1
2019/03/25 - input 2
```

It would not allow putting similar value during the same day there will be a pop up telling that.

But it has to allow to do new inputs next day

```
2019/03/25 - input 1
2019/03/25 - input 2
2019/03/25 - input 3
2019/03/26 - input 1
2019/03/26 - input 2
2019/03/26 - input 3
```

And I do not know how many inputs during the day will be it may vary.  it can be one day 5 next day 11 and another day 1.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Without any indication of what you've already tried, this question is probably too broad for SO.  You have a userform, so you must know *some* VBA, or at least enough to give it a try.

Comment: Also a bunch of information missing - exactly how are you entering these records (text box or ?) and is the data to be checked all contained in the userform, or does data elsewhere need to be checked to ensure no duplicates?

Comment: Place it in a dictionary object key. You can't put duplicate keys in so if it errors you know it's been done already.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. My knowledge ends with available YouTube videos on this subject. I put information using text box, information from that transfers to related cell in excel sheet. The function of all this inputs to track how many times this user form was used during one day. Next day count start new count. So the operator puts all the numbers manually in the text box.